# Restart/Power off background color does not follow Accent color

Tags: windows-10, themes, color-theme

Basically the title. I have a weird issue with Restart/Power Off background color does not follow Accent color in Personalize settings. I personally want it to be Gray color, but it remains in Blue no matter what accent color I choose. I have another PC and do not have this issue.

What I have tried:

1. Boot in Safe mode and Clean boot - same issue.
2. Update to the latest version of Windows (20H0).
3. Reinstall Video card drivers/disable Video Card and make Windows to use generic video driver.

My specs:

Lenovo X220 laptop, Windows 10 x64

[image: Accent Color Settings]

[image: Restart]

[image: Shutdown]

Comment: I have another PC (Win 10 64 Pro) and all aforementioned screens background color follow Accent color, as on this video:

https://youtu.be/U_GNx9stzf4

Comment: according to my research, many users have encountered this issue. Maybe you can try to install third-party theme.